# React/TypeScript testing failed. "Consider using the "jsdom" test environment."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have a very simple React/TypeScript application, and I'm trying to learn how to implement testing. I'm using React Testing Library and Jest. It's a very simple product page, and I just want to test that the words "Welcome to our product page" have rendered.

When I run the test, I get this error message: `The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string. Consider using the "jsdom" test environment. ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

I went through all the solutions in similar questions on Stack Overflow, but nothing is working. I tried adding

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
*/
```

to the top of the test file, but that just produces a different error message: `ReferenceError: global is not defined`.

I'd appreciate any help. Below is my code:

**ProductPage.test.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import ProductPage from "../ProductPage";

describe("<ProductPage />", () => {
  test("should display the product page", () => {
    render(<ProductPage />);
    expect(
        screen.getByText(/Welcome to our product page/)
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {              
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],          

  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/cssTransform.js"
  },       
  
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [        
    "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
  ],    

  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",    

  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "product-page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.17",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/system": "^5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "graphql": "^16.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"    
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use jsdom you need to add

```js
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
```

to your `jest.config.js`

Edit: You might need to add it as a dependency also.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to testing. Do I just add it to anywhere within the `jest.config.js` file? And for the dev dependencies, do I just add `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` under `dependencies` in the `package.json` file? 

I did both of the above, and I'm still getting ` ReferenceError: global is not defined`

Comment: You just add it in your jest.config.js, after `testRegex` for example...

Comment: What I meant is that maybe you don't have jsdom in your (dev)dependencies in the node_moldules, in that case you would have to add it as a devDependency `npm install --dev jsdom` or `yarn add jsdom`

Comment: Thank you. I added it to jest.config and added jsdom as a dev dependency. Still getting `ReferenceError: global is not defined` :(

Comment: Might be related to the `setupFilesAfterEnv` in your jest.config.js. In my case I point to a custom file where I do:
```import '@testing-library/jest-dom';``` so it imports a lot of rules. Config of tooling is nightmare...

Comment: Thanks. Installing `jsdom` did not help, but installing `jest-environment-jsdom` did. Now my tests actually run. I'm still getting an error, but it's related to something else now.

Comment: Glad you solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` to `jest.config.js`. This resolved the jsdom error.
2. Add `jest-environment-jsdom` as a dev dependency (adding `jsdom` did not help for whatever reason). This resolved the global error.